# Qt: How to create a clearly visible glow effect for a QLabel? (e.g. using QGraphicsDropShadowEffect)

Tags: c++, qt, graphics

I am trying to add a glow effect to a QLabel so that it looks like the time display in the following picture:

[image]

I found out that you can "misuse" a `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` for this:

```
QGraphicsDropShadowEffect * dse = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
dse->setBlurRadius(10);
dse->setOffset(0);
dse->setColor(QColor(255, 255, 255));
ui.label->setGraphicsEffect(dse);
```

However, the resulting effect is too weak, you can barely see it:

[image]

Unfortunately, you can not modify the strength of the effect, only color and blur radius.

One idea would be to apply multiple `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` to the label, so that it gets more visible due to overlapping. But calling `ui.label->setGraphicsEffect(dse);` will always delete any previous effects, i.e. I was not able to set multiple `QGraphicsEffect` to the same object.

Any ideas how you can create a clearly visible glow effect with Qt?

Answer (score 5):

Meanwhile, I tinkered my own graphics effect based on `QGraphicsBlurEffect` and using parts of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28026710/4415923). If you know any better solutions, let me know.

**qgraphicsgloweffect.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include <QGraphicsEffect>
#include <QGraphicsBlurEffect>
#include <QGraphicsColorizeEffect>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QPainter>

class QGraphicsGlowEffect :
  public QGraphicsEffect
{
public:
  explicit QGraphicsGlowEffect(QObject *parent = 0);

  QRectF boundingRectFor(const QRectF &rect) const;
  void setColor(QColor value);
  void setStrength(int value);
  void setBlurRadius(qreal value);
  QColor color() const;
  int strength() const;
  qreal blurRadius() const;

protected:
  void draw(QPainter* painter);

private:
  static QPixmap applyEffectToPixmap(QPixmap src, QGraphicsEffect *effect, int extent);
  int _extent = 5;
  QColor _color = QColor(255, 255, 255);
  int _strength = 3;
  qreal _blurRadius = 5.0;
};
```

**qgraphicsgloweffect.cpp:**

```
#include "QGraphicsGlowEffect.h"
#include <QtCore\qmath.h>

QGraphicsGlowEffect::QGraphicsGlowEffect(QObject *parent) : QGraphicsEffect(parent)
{
}

void QGraphicsGlowEffect::setColor(QColor value) {
  _color = value;
}

void QGraphicsGlowEffect::setStrength(int value) {
  _strength = value;
}

void QGraphicsGlowEffect::setBlurRadius(qreal value) {
  _blurRadius = value;
  _extent =  qCeil(value);
  updateBoundingRect();
}

QColor QGraphicsGlowEffect::color() const {
  return _color;
}

int QGraphicsGlowEffect::strength() const {
  return _strength;
}

qreal QGraphicsGlowEffect::blurRadius() const {
  return _blurRadius;
}

QRectF QGraphicsGlowEffect::boundingRectFor(const QRectF &rect) const {
  return QRect(
      rect.left() - _extent,
      rect.top() - _extent,
      rect.width() + 2 * _extent, 
      rect.height() + 2 * _extent);
}

void QGraphicsGlowEffect::draw(QPainter* painter) {
  QPoint offset;
  QPixmap source = sourcePixmap(Qt::LogicalCoordinates, &offset);
  QPixmap glow;

  QGraphicsColorizeEffect *colorize = new QGraphicsColorizeEffect;
  colorize->setColor(_color);
  colorize->setStrength(1);
  glow = applyEffectToPixmap(source, colorize, 0);

  QGraphicsBlurEffect *blur = new QGraphicsBlurEffect;
  blur->setBlurRadius(_blurRadius);
  glow = applyEffectToPixmap(glow, blur, _extent);

  for (int i = 0; i < _strength; i++)
    painter->drawPixmap(offset - QPoint(_extent, _extent), glow);
  drawSource(painter);
}

QPixmap QGraphicsGlowEffect::applyEffectToPixmap(
  QPixmap src, QGraphicsEffect *effect, int extent)
{
  if (src.isNull()) return QPixmap();
  if (!effect) return src;
  QGraphicsScene scene;
  QGraphicsPixmapItem item;
  item.setPixmap(src);
  item.setGraphicsEffect(effect);
  scene.addItem(&item);
  QSize size = src.size() + QSize(extent * 2, extent * 2);
  QPixmap res(size.width(), size.height());
  res.fill(Qt::transparent);
  QPainter ptr(&res);
  scene.render(&ptr, QRectF(), QRectF(-extent, -extent, size.width(), size.height()));
  return res;
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
QGraphicsGlowEffect * glow = new QGraphicsGlowEffect();
glow->setStrength(4);
glow->setBlurRadius(7);
ui.label->setGraphicsEffect(glow);
```

This results in a nice glow effect:

[image]