# Blur an image in QML without using QtGraphicalEffects

Tags: qt, qml, blur

I want to make an image blur in QML without using the QtGraphicalEffects support.

If it is possible, can somebody please share me the sample to achieve this?

Comment: You could manually write your own `ShaderEffect`.

Comment: You can overlay your image by a rectangle with background cover image of a transparent blur image

Comment: See [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903223/qt4-how-to-blur-qpixmap-image)